# How to create Element with text and tags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I has create next XML:

```
item = E('p') # <p/>
```

Now I need to put next content into it:

```
text = "some <bold>text</bold>"

# item.append(text) 
# TypeError: Argument 'element' has incorrect type (expected lxml.etree._Element, got str)

# item.append(fromstring(text)) 
# lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

I need as result next XML node:

```
<p>some <bold>text</bold></p>
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 6):

You need to create sub-elements:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("p")
root.text = 'some'

bold = etree.SubElement(root, 'bold')
bold.text = 'text'

print (etree.tostring(root))
```

Returns:

```
<p>some<bold>text</bold></p>
```

Comment: Thank you! And give please advice, how to obtain next result: `<p>some <bold>text</bold> more</p>`

Comment: You should use a [templating engine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) to generate the HTML markup instead of making it manually.

Comment: But I create an parser, I need some XML document as result. Conception of views is not appropriate for my project... Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the [offical docs](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.builder.ElementMaker-class.html)